# Trouble opening a file in linux

Tags: c, linux, fgets

I am trying to print running processes on a linux system, but I am getting a segmentation fault when trying to do so.  Here is my code:

```
FILE *ps;
char line[256];
char * command = "ps";  
ps = fopen(command, "r");
if(ps == NULL){
    perror("Error");
}
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), ps)){
    printf("%s", line);
}
fclose(ps);
```

The odd thing is that when I use the same code but replace "ps" with "/proc/meminfo" or other files, it will correctly output.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Well, does `fopen` succeed or fail? Why don't you test?

Comment: Do you have a file called `ps`?

Comment: `ps` is not a file, it is a command.  At least that's true based on the way you want to use it.

Comment: Yes, it says it doesn't exist.  How then would I get the data from the command "ps" into a string?

Comment: Have a look into the `system()` man page.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/478898/951890

Comment: Post the solution as an answer. Don't edit your question. It's totally fine to self-answer questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) and pclose for running command rather than fopen and fclose

```
char line[256];
FILE *ps = popen("ps", "r");
if(ps == NULL){
    perror("Error");
}

while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), ps)){
    printf("%s", line);
}

pclose(ps);
```